# API access via Jquery issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to access an API via jquery with ajax , here's my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function kimonoCallback(data) {
   var ticker = '<ul id="webticker">';
   var url = data.results.collection[i].alaune; 
   $.each(url,function(i, news ){       
     ticker += '<li>';
     ticker += '<a href="'+ news.href+ '">';
     ticker += '<img src="img/ticker_sep.png" alt="sep"/>';
     ticker += '"'+ news.text +'" </a></li>';
   });
   ticker += '</ul>';
   $('#tickernews').html(ticker);
  }



$.ajax({
        "url":"https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/d7dujppi?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&callback=kimonoCallback",
        "crossDomain":true,
        "dataType":"jsonp"
    });

});
```

when i try to see the results in the webpage nothing come up  no error in the console. so how do i make the request and display the text my webpage.

check the api [here](https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/d7dujppi?apikey=94d5808efe01f5eab40a5027c54bf86f)

Comment: Does the server from which you are requesting the data allow cross-domain requests? The headers returned by the API link you gave don't have any origin headers set.

Comment: yeah the server accept CORS

Comment: it gives reponse with json but not with jsonp so it is not allowing jsonp i think

Comment: i fixed it , i add to add the CORS domain in order for the server to answer the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6jU3b/5/

Call your method in the [success method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) of the ajax response rather than trying to execute it when returned from the server.

I also changed your `$.each` statement a bit to reflect the updated  object (you changed it from `collection` to `collection1` while I was working on it :{

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/d7dujppi?apikey=94d5808efe01f5eab40a5027c54bf86f",
        crossDomain:true,
        dataType:"jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            kimonoCallback(data);
        }

    });

function kimonoCallback(data) {
   var ticker = '<ul id="webticker">';
   var url = data.results.collection1; 
   $.each(url,function(key, value){       
     ticker += '<li>';
     ticker += '<a href="'+ value.alaune.href + '">';
     ticker += '<img src="img/ticker_sep.png" alt="sep"/>';
     ticker += '"'+ value.alaune.text +'" </a></li>';
   });

   ticker += '</ul>';
   $('#tickernews').html(ticker);
 }

});
```

Comment: No problem! Glad we got it figured out